# match exact word not with any suffix or prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to select color name within property block i.e. within curly braces `{` and using below regex

```js
'\\b(red|black)\\b';
```

```js
const rgx = '\\b(red|black)\\b';

const rex = new RegExp(rgx, 'igmd');
const text = `
body {
  padding: 2px;
  color: red;
}

.red {
    color:black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

`;

const matches = text.matchAll(rex);

console.log(Array.from(matches));
```

but this one select the selector (.red ) also which is not the requirement. How can I achieve this as I think that if we create regex which select exact word not with any suffix of prefix and suffix can be *.*, *#*, *~* or other, ( please note, I have minimize the regex in the above example for the brevity)

Comment: with help of @Tim answer, this is I have done https://regex101.com/r/JIUTKp/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can match on the `color` attribute here:

```js
const text = `
body {
  padding: 2px;
  color: red;
}

.red {
    color:black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

`;

const matches = text.match(/\b[\w-]+\s*:\s*(?:red|black)\b/g)
                    .map(x => x.split(":")[1].trim());

console.log(Array.from(matches));
```

Comment: its not specific to `color:` property , it might be any property like backgroundf-color, filter, border

Comment: Then check the updated answer, which should now work for any property.

Comment: Thanks. but I am using matchAll here and it selct the complete line i.e. `'background-color: red'`  while I need to select only color, I see you use .map later to split but can we use npn capture group here somehow?

Comment: My answer gives you only the color.  Did you look at it?

Comment: yes but using .map while I am using .matchAll as I written that the code above is just a part and my other code do not suffice this much changes., I have to use it wothout map , hope you understand

Comment: I don't think either `match` or `matchAll` will work here using a capture group as you require.

Comment: because matchAll gives Array type return which have inidices and other propert while .match do not provide so.

Comment: with your answer I have modified regex a bit and it is working: https://regex101.com/r/e45IBw/1  can you please check is that correct approach?

Comment: Yes it looks OK to me.

Comment: @diEcho Please consider _accepting_ this answer, if it pointed you in the right direction, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.